# how to replace \\n with \n

Tags: javascript, node.js

as shown in the below posted code, in the  `code` section, i pass `jsonreq` to `createOptionsFor()` and assign it to  `body` object. the `jsonreq` should contain the object shown in `jsonreq` section below.
but what happens is, when i print out the contents of `body: JSON.stringify(jsonreq)` i got the output shown in the `output` section below. as illustrated in the latter section, all the new lines are represented as `\\n` notation, but such notation mangles the
`evalscript` because the `evalscript` object should reach the server where all the new lines are represented as  `\n` and not `\\n`

to solve this issue, i did the following

```
body:JSON.stringify(jsonreq).replace('\\\\n','\\n')
```

but when i print the contents of the latter statement/command i find that still all the new lines are represented as `\\n`
please let me know why that is happening and how to solve it

**code**:

```
class HTTPAPI {
#options = undefined;
#agent = undefined;

constructor() {
    this.#options = undefined
    this.#agent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
        proxy: {
            host: 'xx.xx-xx.xx',
            port: '3000',
        },
    });
}

createOptionsFor(reqMethod, headers, jsonreq) {
    return this.#options = {
        agent: this.#agent,
        protocol: resources.PROTOCOL_HTTPS.description,
        host: resources.HOST.description,
        path: encodeURI (
            resources.PATH.description +
            resources.PROCESS.description
        ),
        method: reqMethod,
        headers: headers,
        body:JSON.stringify(jsonreq)
    };
}
....
....
....
```

}
module.exports = HTTPAPI;

**jsonreq**:

```
....
....
....
"evalscript": `//VERSION=3
          function setup() {
              return {
                input: [{
                  bands: ["B01", "B08"],
                  units: "DM"
                }],
                output: {
                  bands: 1,
                  sampleType: SampleType.FLOAT32
                },
                mosaicking: Mosaicking.ORBIT
              }
            }

            function updateOutput(outputs, collection) {
                Object.values(outputs).forEach((output) => {
                    output.bands = collection.scenes.length;
                });
            }
            function updateOutputMetadata(scenes, inputMetadata, outputMetadata) {
                var dds = [];
                for (i=0; i<scenes.length; i++){
                  dds.push(scenes[i].date)
                }
                outputMetadata.userData = { "acquisition_dates":  JSON.stringify(dds) }
            }
            
            function evaluatePixel(samples) {
              var n_observations = samples.length;
              let ndvi = new Array(n_observations).fill(0);
              samples.forEach((sample, index) => {
                ndvi[index] = (sample.B08/2 - sample.B04/2) / (sample.B08/4 + sample.B04) ;
              });        
              return ndvi;
            }`
```

**output**:

```
body: '.....,"evalscript":"//VERSION=3\\n              function setup() {\\n                  return {\\n                    input: [{\\n                      bands: [\\"B04\\", \\"B08\\"],\\n                      units: \\"DN\\"\\n                    }],\\n                    output: {\\n                      bands: 1,\\n                      sampleType: SampleType.FLOAT32\\n                    },\\n                    mosaicking: Mosaicking.ORBIT\\n                  }\\n                }\\n\\n                function updateOutput(outputs, collection) {\\n                    Object.values(outputs).forEach((output) => {\\n                        output.bands = collection.scenes.length;\\n                    });\\n                }\\n                function updateOutputMetadata(scenes, inputMetadata, outputMetadata) {\\n                    var dds = [];\\n                    for (i=0; i<scenes.length; i++){\\n                      dds.push(scenes[i].date)\\n                    }\\n                    outputMetadata.userData = { \\"acquisition_dates\\":  JSON.stringify(dds) }\\n                }\\n                \\n                function evaluatePixel(samples) {\\n                  var n_observations = samples.length;\\n                  let ndvi = new Array(n_observations).fill(0);\\n                  samples.forEach((sample, index) => {\\n                    ndvi[index] = (sample.B08 - sample.B04) / (sample.B08 + sample.B04) ;\\n                  });        \\n                  return ndvi;\\n                }"}'
```

Comment: don't you want `replaceAll('\n', '\\n')` - but then your JSON may not be valid JSON any more

Comment: @JaromandaX i want to replace all the occurances of \\n with \n

Comment: Are you sure these are `\\n` to begin with? I think you are chasing a red herring and looking at a Javascript string representation (which escapes its backslashes in the output but that's only so that the output is a valid string literal again that represents the same thing - the string doesn't actually contain these extra backslashes)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what `i find that still all the new lines are represented as \\n` meant - I thought you had actual newlines somehow

Comment: @CherryDT would you please tell me what does `a red herring` mean?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring#:~:text=A%20red%20herring%20is%20something,audiences%20toward%20a%20false%20conclusion - something misleading that's not actually relevant. My point is that you are chasing a ghost because the `\\n` you see is simply a JS string representation of `\n`. There is nothing wrong here, your problem isn't actually a problem.

Comment: Try `console.log(this.#options.body)` to see the actual string sent, not `console.log(this.#options)` which will show a string literal inside an object